# Multiple SFTP Servers sharing common chroot path logging issue

Tags: ssh, logging, sftp, rsyslog

I am setting up an SFTP service with multiple EC2 instances for High Availability on AWS with a common EFS Share (mounted at `/efs/sftp`).

```
            ,--------,
            |        |
            |  SFTP  |-------,
 -----      |________|       |    ,-----------------,
| NLB |                      |    |                 |
 -----                       |----| EFS (/efs/sftp) |
            ,--------,       |    |_________________|
            |        |       |
            | SFTP   |-------'
            |________|
```

I am using chroot with SFTP to force users to only have access to `/efs/sftp`. For the chroot'ed activities to be logged I have created `/efs/sftp/dev` and inside that I have configured rsyslog socket using `imuxsock` (`/efs/sftp/dev/log`).

I am mostly following this blog to configure my SFTP server. (https://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/sftp-logging-chroot/).

One problem with the setup is since both servers have identical configuration (for `rsyslog`, `sftp`) <s>both the rsyslogs instances would get logs from `/efs/sftp/dev/log`. Wouldn't both the servers write same logs into `/var/log/sftp.log`?</s> the rsyslog instance in which the socket was created is the only one able to log the activities in chroot.

The logs from these instances (`/var/log/sftp.log`) are streamed to centralised logging servers (Splunk) <s>and would eventually have duplicates.</s>

<s>Whats the best option to avoid this duplication?</s> What is the best way to get logs from chroot SFTP activity on both the servers?

Edit: I tried this today and found that only one server is able to get the logs. Updated the question.

Comment: What duplication? I don't see any duplication here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, Thank you for having a look. I tried this out and found that only one server (from which rsyslog socket got created) was able to get the logs, which rsyslog then wrote to `/var/log/sftp.log`.

How do I get both the servers to log its activity from chroot into `/var/log/sftp.log`?

I have updated the question with my new findings. Sorry for posting too early without trying it out.